# How to fix problem with Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbContextAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Hotel   C:\Users\Adis\source\repos\webapp\Hotel\Hotel\Migrations\20200625154358_firstOne.Designer.cs    12  Active

I have problem with designer.cs file, some files are deleted from my device, after that i can't build my project. Anyone have idea what to do ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know which files were deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling (if installed) EntityFramework and re-installing. Failing that, please post what references you currently have.

Comment: Now i have this error, previous one is fixed.  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\Users\Adis\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.workspaces.common\3.3.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll" because it was not found. Hotel C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4360

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you will have to reinstall Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common through NuGet directly from what I can tell in the stacktrace posted. Unfortunately I could not assist beyond that.

Comment: Now everything works fine, main problem was about that some nuget packages were missing. Thank you one more time.